# Remove dynamically generated textboxes

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript that dynamically add textboxes together with a remove button to a div. How can I using the remove button delete the content of the row being selected to delete?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return('' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.EndDate" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.Description" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>' +
        '</div>');
}
function AddTextBox() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.className = "form-group";
    div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
    document.getElementById("divcontent").appendChild(div);
}
function RemoveTextBox(div) {
    //document.getElementById("divcontent").removeChild(div.parentNode); // this does not work
iterateBoxesAndSetUniqueIds();
}

function iterateBoxesAndSetUniqueIds() {
    // Set unique names of each textbox
    var children = document.getElementById("divcontent").children; 
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
    {
        var el = children[i];
        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Key'; // 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Key';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.StartDate';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.EndDate';

        el.name = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description'; 
        el.id = 'events[' + i + '].Value.Description';
    }
}


</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="AddTextBox()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Add</button>

        <div id="divcontent">

        </div>
```

UPDATE
I added a snippet for updating the id for each textbox, but obviously I am doing something wrong here. Can anyone help with this too?

Comment: The parent node would be the `col-md-2` div, is that the element you intend to remove?

Comment: Well, if the user click remove, then all textboxes and the remove button should be removed. So the following should be removed.. events[0].Key, events[0].Value.StartDate, events[0].Value.EndDate, events[0].Value.Description and the button for that row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to remove the entire row, so heres how to do that.

You almost had it, since you pass `(this)` in the `onclick`, it means we have a direct reference to the button that was clicked. From there, we can get its grandparent by using `.parentNode` twice (since the first parent is `.col-md-2`) and then use the `remove()` function.

`div.parentNode.parentNode.remove()`

```js
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return('' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.EndDate" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.Description" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(this)"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>' +
        '</div>');
}
function AddTextBox() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.className = "form-group";
    div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
    document.getElementById("divcontent").appendChild(div);
}
function RemoveTextBox(div) {
   div.parentNode.parentNode.remove()
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="AddTextBox()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Add</button>

<div id="divcontent">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function GetDynamicTextBox(value, uniquedId) {
        return('' +
            '<div class="col-md-2">' +
            '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value=""/>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-2">' +
            '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value=""/>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-2">' +
            '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.EndDate" value=""/>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-2">' +
            '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.Description" value=""/>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-2">' +
            '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(\'' + uniquedId +'\')"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>' +
            '</div>');
    }
    function AddTextBox() {
        var uniquedId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '_unique';
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.setAttribute("id", uniquedId);
        div.className = "form-group";
        div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("", uniquedId);
        document.getElementById("divcontent").appendChild(div);
    }
    function RemoveTextBox(uniquedId) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(uniquedId);
    return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="AddTextBox()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Add</button>
    
            <div id="divcontent">
    
            </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetDynamicTextBox(value, uniquedId) {
    return('' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Key" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.StartDate" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.EndDate" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <input type="text" name="events[0].Value.Description" value=""/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-2">' +
        '  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="RemoveTextBox(\'' + uniquedId +'\')"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Remove</button>' +
        '</div>');
}
function AddTextBox() {
    var uniquedId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '_unique';
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.setAttribute("id", uniquedId);
    div.className = "form-group";
    div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("", uniquedId);
    document.getElementById("divcontent").appendChild(div);
}
function RemoveTextBox(uniquedId) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(uniquedId);
return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}


</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="AddTextBox()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Add</button>

        <div id="divcontent">

        </div>
```